# How to escape $ in the value in replaceAll

Tags: java

For example

```
String updateValue(String value) {
return "PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replaceAll("PLACEHOLDER", value);
}

updateValue("$3");
```

Expected output is `$3 $3`, but it will throw error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 3` due to the char `$`. How to update the function `updateValue` so that it will output the expected result?

Here is what I have tried

```
String updateValue(String value) {
return "PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replaceAll("PLACEHOLDER", value.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\$"));
}
```

But it did not work, getting error `Illegal group reference: group index is missing`

Comment: `System.out.println("PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replaceAll("PLACEHOLDER", "\\$3"));`

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the question, can you check again?

Comment: `System.out.println(updateValue("\\$3"));`

Answer (score 1):

`"PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replaceAll("PLACEHOLDER", "\\$3")`

Comment: Thank you! I just updated the question, can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

```
String updateValue(String value) {
return "PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replaceAll("PLACEHOLDER", value.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$"));
}
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

As your search string is not making use of regular expression you can use the standard search and replace call `String.replace`. Then the replace pattern does not need to be escaped:

```
"PLACEHOLDER PLACEHOLDER".replace("PLACEHOLDER", "$3");
==> "$3 $3"
```